# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key ""

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0
I am setting connecting string run time. (Default connection string.)

When Following line is executed,

```
 Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

I am getting error, "Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key """

At same time, in app config, there is connecting string.

However, on restarting application, it works fine.

I have also checked [Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "" <-- blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030436/activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-instance-of-type-database-key) , but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a "defaultDatabase" that points to one of your connection strings.  Here I am setting it to "MainConnectionString".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </configSections>

  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="MainConnectionString">



<connectionStrings>

  <!-- Sql Server(s) -->
  <add name="MainConnectionString" connectionString="Server=.\MyInstance;Database=pubs;Trusted_Connection=True;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>


</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: That is already done, but my connection string was blank before run. When connection string is blank, I am setting connection string. But even after that I am getting error. While restarting application is working fine.